# How i can run a pig script in local mode on HUE cluster? my input and output dir is on local file system where hue is installed

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, hue

How i can run a  pig script  in local mode on HUE cluster? 
my input and output  dir  is on local file system where hue is installed

Comment: pig -x local is not working for you?

Comment: I am running following commands from pig UI                                 pig -x LOCAL
a= load 'a.txt' using PigStorage(',');
dump a;                                                                                                                 I am getting error like --:2016-04-07 09:35:40,109 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "pig "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of: